# How to using mod rewrite on main index page?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How do I use mod_rewrite in `index.php`? Generally I am using this code:

```
RewriteRule ^page/([^-]*)/([^-]*)$ /page.php?xxx=$1&yyy=$2 [L]
```

and loading the page `www.example.com/page/11111/2222222`.

This works as expected. But now I want to apply `.htaccess` for using url in this format: `www.example.com/11111/2222222` and use all code in `page.php`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, remove the `page/` from your rule and use this way:

```
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)/([^-]*)$ /page.php?xxx=$1&yyy=$2 [L]
```

Comment: it's work , but all my css and layout every page are mistake, why?

Comment: You have to use the CSS document positioned from root! In your `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />`, use this way: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

In .htacces

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+/?)$ page.php?url=$1 [NC]
```

And then, in page.php:

```
$params = explode("/", $url);
//$params[0] = '11111', $params[1] = '2222222', and so on....
```

Comment: only one, but you can force get variables like this:

$_GET = explode("/", $url);